# how to save cmd command's return warning

Tags: android, cmd, adb

how to save cmd command's return warning.
The command I used:
 `adb shell am start -a android.settings.AIRPLANE_MODE_SETTINGS > result.txt`
then on cmd display the result and return message as follows:
`Starting: Intent { act=android.settings.AIRPLANE_MODE_SETTINGS }`
 `Warning: Activity not started, intent has been delivered to currently running top-most instance`.
But in the result.txt file there is only save: `Starting: Intent { act=android.settings.AIRPLANE_MODE_SETTINGS }` and the Warning message is not saved. can someone explain and help me save the dc warning returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `2>&1` to the end of your command.  That redirects stderr to stdout, which is most likely where the error is being printed to

Comment: tks u. it work fine